# In "Some statement. This!", what does the "This!" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have seen a expression or phrase of the following form:

*Some statement.* **This!**

The "This!" seems to be something like an acknowledgement.

Is there a more verbose explanation or translation of it?

Comment: I conjecture that the meaning depends on what happened just before it was said.

Comment: Commonly used to emphasize that what was just stated is a true and relevant.

Comment: ^ This! (You could make that an answer @HotLicks.)

Comment: A few examples would help.

Comment: @WalterMitty True, but I do not have any at hand, and they are exceptionally hard to google...

Comment: @nnnnnn Or alternatively you! I assume the "^" means that it is associated with the comment above, that would normally directly in front of it.

Comment: You really do need at least one example to give the proper context. What people have guessed here is probably correct, but there's no way to tell without more information in your question.

Comment: But of course an answer needs a reference, not a bare assertion "commonly used".

Answer (score 2):

> Person A: In the Monty Python sketch, why didn't the woman like spam?
>
> Person B: Have you ever eaten spam? It's horrible! She wanted something without spam.
>
> Person C: **It's horrible!** [This!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/this#Interjection)

What person C is saying is that the statement before "This!" summarises the argument perfectly and that they agree with it 100%. They believe that the statement is sufficient by itself to wrap up the discussion.

From Wiktionary:

> #### Interjection
>
> [**this**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/this#Interjection)
>
> *(Internet slang) Indicates the speaker's strong approval or agreement with the previous material.*

Comment: Needs a reference.

Answer (score 2):

In internet usage, [a bare *this*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=This) usually means, "I could not say this better myself, the previous quote should be considered authoritative.